# Meaning of "Darling she said 'I was yours to be seen'" in Desmond Dekker's Israelites?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, reggae

What is the meaning of the "Darling she said 'I was yours to be seen'" lyric in the song Israeliates by Desmond Dekker?

Comment: "seen" in [Jamaican english](https://jamaicanpatwah.com/term/seen/2478)  usually means "ok, agreed, understood"

Answer (score 1):

It's a mis-heard lyric.
The line is "'Darling', she said, 'I was yours to receive.'"

Source - [Trojan Records Official YouTube channel, video with lyrics.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wSXTN2EfRo)

[image]

Not that that makes it much clearer to comprehend;)

Comment: for me the lyric makes most sense as a list of stresses and disasters in the life of a [suffera](https://jamaicanpatwah.com/term/suffera/2413) - like the Israelite slaves in Egypt in the biblical account : "wake up early slaving for bread so/ every mouth can be fed", "wife and kids pack up and leave" etc

Comment: Thanks at least that's a more authoritative source for the lyric - but I would still like to know what it means.